# Avoiding Structure Padding in C

Tags: c, structure, padding

How we can avoid structure padding in C apart from using pragma pack aur bit field?
Is there any other method available?

Comment: I have to ask.. Why? (and yes, there are several methods, every one of the borderline-bletcherous).

Answer (score 7):

Pack the biggest items at the start of the structure.  Pack smaller items towards the end.

```
struct optimal_packing
{
     double d;
     int    i[4];
     short  j[3];
     char   s[24];
};
```

To be slightly more accurate, it is the items with the most stringent alignment requirements that need to come earliest (which tend to be pointers and `double` or perhaps `long double`), and those with less stringent alignment requirements at the end (`short` and `char`).  You can still end up with tail padding if the total length of the components adds up to, say 35 bytes, but one of the types requires an 8-byte alignment; there'd be 5 bytes of padding.

Comment: +1: I totally support this answer, though even it is not a guarantee. An AS/400, for example, will align every member in a structure on a 16-byte boundary if there is even *one* pointer variable held within. For platforms that aren't as ludicrous, this is likely the easiest option to try.

Comment: what about a union of char array and struct ? would that be guaranteed not to be padded ?

Comment: @WhozCraig: I hadn't heard about that behaviour of C on AS/400.  Interesting indeed.  This is still the best you can do, but it won't prevent there being holes in the structure on an AS/400.  On most systems, though, it will do a decent job.

Comment: I concur, Jonathan. I was about to answer this with the same answer caveat briefly mentioned). The alignment on the 400 is how they validate pointers as non-null (another issue entirely, and frankly something to behold, since on a 400, a null-pointer does not necessarily mean a "zero" pointer).

Comment: @mux: I'd need to see how you're defining your union...It begins to be tricky.

Comment: Heh. I just checked my ref, and as of the 244938 redbook they only force 16-byte boundaries on pointer members *unless there are non-pointer-members sandwiched between them.* All pointers (struct or not) on a 400 must be on 16-byte-aligned addresses. As you can imagine it makes for fascinating packs when you have non-adjacent pointer members in your struct. So this is most definitely the best answer.

Comment: @WhozCraig: That makes a lot more sense.  On AS/400, pointers first, then all the other bits.  But the 16-byte alignment on pointers means they're likely to be the most stringently aligned type anyway.

Comment: You are absolutely correct; they are definitely the most stringently aligned. Long doubles and ints are the closest, at 8-bytes.

Comment: This doesn't really solve anything if the reason to avoid padding is  to follow a given bits & bytes spec (which is the most likely reason). Ending up with padding at the end would be just as bad in that case. And even still, the compiler is free to add padding anywhere in the struct/union, except before the very first element.

Comment: @Lundin: It doesn't guarantee anything, but it does minimize the internal padding in a structure if you get the order correct.  Yes, the compiler can add padding anywhere after the first member; no, the compiler won't do it on a whim.  If you're working to a specific memory layout, you often have to use machine-specific techniques to meet the requirements.  And this technique doesn't deal with marshalling/unmarshalling (or serializing/deserializing) data for transmission over a network connection, in general.

Comment: Don't some compilers put even 16 bit ints and chars at 32 or 16 bit boundaries because access is faster?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica depends on target platform ABI, it's generally not random between compilers on the same architecture and OS mix. Although there can be ABI breaks. But I can't think of anything requiring over-alignment off the top of my head. Maybe Alpha AXP?

Answer (score 3):

The only completely portable and reliable way to avoid structure padding is not to use real members in your `struct` at all. Use a single `char` array member, and define macros that access its contents:

```
struct paddingless {
    // char *p;
    // double d;
    // char c;

#define OFFSET_P 0
#define OFFSET_D (OFFSET_P + sizeof(char *))
#define OFFSET_C (OFFSET_D + sizeof(double))    
#define OFFSET_END (OFFSET_C + sizeof(char))    

    char data[OFFSET_END];
};
```

Portable getters and setters would look like this:

```
inline double paddingless_get_d(const struct paddingless *o) {
    double val;
    memcpy(&val, o->data + OFFSET_D, sizeof(val));
    return val;
}
inline void paddingless_set_d(struct paddingless *o, double val) {
    memcpy(o->data + OFFSET_D, &val, sizeof(val));
}
```

If you know that your architecture accepts unaligned access, you can get away with a setter being defined with a cast:

```
#define paddingless_get_d(o) (*(double *) ((o)->data + OFFSET_D))
#define paddingless_set_d(o, val) (*(double *) ((o)->data + OFFSET_D) = (val))
```

This is non-portable, but potentially faster than the alternative. And it works on a <strike>vax</strike> x86...

Comment: +1. Actually, with a decent compiler, the portable version is just as fast; compilers understand "memcpy" pretty well.  The real advantage of the non-portable version is that `paddingless_get_d` (perhaps better named `paddingless_d`) is an lvalue, so you can pass its address to a function expecting pointer-to-double etc.  But then, it's non-portable, so you might be just as well off with a pragma.

Comment: @Nemo `memcpy` with constant size is optimized, but the portable version still takes care not to access unaligned memory as it would a `double`. For example, `get_d(o) + 1.0` will need to do a bit more work in the portable version. As for the pragma, it's a different kind of non-portability: the pragma assumes a compiler that groks it, whereas an unaligned cast assumes an architecture that groks it. The former is useful if you know that your code will be compiled with say `gcc`; the latter if you know that it will run on say x86, but possibly compiled with a non-gcc compiler such as Sun cc.

Answer (score 1):

There are some things to consider. First of all, the compiler adds padding for a reason: it tries to make the optimal, working machine code for its designated platform. So normally padding is a good thing. Except for the cases where you want to define data communications protocols, hardware register mappings and similar, where the number of bytes simply must match a certain specification.

There is really no standard way to avoid padding. The best you can achieve is a compile time assert giving an error if the struct size doesn't match the sum of all its individual members. When the assert fails, you go and change the compiler settings to block padding. Preferably:

`static_assert(sizeof(mystruct) == (sizeof(mystruct.x) + sizeof(mystruct.y) +...));`

If static_assert isn't available in your C compiler (you'd need a C11 compliant one), then use some "ct_assert" macro, you can find plenty on this site.

However, this doesn't solve the problem in a portable manner, you would be dependent on compiler settings. The only truly portable way to solve the problem is something like this:

```
void mystruct_copy_from (uint8_t* raw_data, const mystruct_t* ms)
{
  memcpy(raw_data, &ms->x, sizeof(ms->x));
  raw_data += sizeof(ms->x);

  memcpy(raw_data, &ms->y, sizeof(ms->y));
  raw_data += sizeof(ms->y);

  // ... and so on
}


uint8_t protocol [EXPECTED_STRUCT_SIZE];
mystruct_copy_from (protocol, &mystruct);

send(protocol); // some data communication interface without padding
```